Is there any direct evidence for or against the idea of an alternate ending to Big?
There have long been rumors about a supposed alternate ending of the 1988 fantasy movie Big, in which the adult female lead appears as a child in Josh's classroom (presumably after having made a wish at the Zoltar machine). This 1000+ comment thread for example contains posts from many people who claim to remember this alternate ending.  In my opinion, this alternate ending never happened, but I admit there's no direct evidence.
Is there any direct evidence either way. I'd accept:
Pro-alternate ending:

Script or shooting schedule including the scene

Statement from actors, crew, director, producer involved

Actual footage (of course)


Anti-alternate ending

Explicit statement from director/producer/actor denying an alternate ending (Tom Hanks wouldn't count, since he wouldn't necessarily have been on set for the filming of a scene without him in it).


You're describing the end of 14 Going on 30, a film that aired in the same year; https://youtu.be/6783tkwbZw0?si=NeqV0ROy9fqiziXh

I believe that, but it's not conclusive

I have quite a vivid memory of the end of 14 going on 30 where she smiles sheepishly, tucks her hair behind her ear and says "I made a wish..." but I'm pretty sure it's a false memory.

Speaking of that, the people who saw Big in theaters at age 14 would have been just about going on 30 when they posted those comments. Anyone younger and it would be more than half of their life. And they may have only seen the movie once back then.

As is the wont of Hollywood, when a (no pun intended) big movie idea hits with audiences, there's a tendency to make a lot of similar plots. There's not one but two movies made around the same time as Big (1988) that do feature the sort of ending you talk about.
14 going on 30 (made-for-TV movie, 1988). A boy has a crush on his teacher and winds up as an adult male who is mistaken for the new principal. She falls for him as an adult. As linked by Valorum in comments, the teacher watches him revert and then reverts herself as well to be with him. The movie ends with her sitting next to him in class.



The credits on IMDB list a "young Peggy" played by Amy Hathaway

There was also an Italian movie called Da Grande (1987) which is described as

On the day of his eighth birthday, Marco wishes to be a grown-up man and, suddenly, it happens.

The woman in that movie apparently wishes to remain with the boy and becomes a girl as a result (video clip). That final scene happens in a school, but not a classroom.
Disproving a negative
IMDB notes this

Some believe that a home video release of this movie in New Zealand included an alternate ending. The alternate ending allegedly shows young Josh sitting in his classroom at school when he turns around to notice a young female classmate of whom who he recognizes as Susan- who went back to the fairground machine and wished that she was Josh's age. Some claim that this version was also seen on Latin American television. The Book of Lists, Canadian Edition, 2005 includes the following account: "In the original version, there was an additional scene at the end, in which Josh is back at school and a new girl named Susan arrives. The implication is that Susan went back to the carnival machine to make herself Josh's age. Due to negative audience feedback, the scene was cut from the movie."

There's no comments I can find anywhere from the cast, crew, or any writers that this was ever made. Despite the rumors above, no home videos in New Zealand have this ending. IMDB also lists no "young Susan", and no actress has ever claimed to have portrayed her (it would be the only scene she appeared in).
Contrast this with Little Shop of Horrors (1986) which has two endings and both are available. It's strange that, despite people insisting that the theatrical version of Big differed (where thousands of copies were made), nobody has a copy of this version anywhere. Instead, there are two movies, made around the same time, with the same basic plot that end with the female love interest choosing to de-age to stay with the younger male. It's hard not to come to the conclusion that people are conflating these other versions that do end this way.

First, +1. Second... wow. I wonder if they would greenlight this movie with genders reversed: the protagonist is a 14 year old girl with a crush on a 30 year old teacher, and the movie ends with the older teacher transforming into 14 so that he could romance the young girl. Yuck...

They already did; it's called Twilight. But jokes (?) aside, I think any of these movies would be much less likely to be made now, since audiences have become much more critical about the portrayal of relationships in media in general (and less likely to just focus on what "looks good" on screen), more aware that sexual predators and their victims come in all genders, and increasingly cognizant of how exploitative, psychologically damaging and sexually predatory almost all such relationships are in real life.

FWIW, this seems to corroborate the confusion with Big: https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/14_Going_on_30#Trivia

My position on "disproving a negative" in answers here on SO is that if the evidence that there should be evidence reaches a certain point, its quite reasonable to assert the negative and put the burden of proof on anyone who claims otherwise. People don't get to just make up any random thing (Aliens planted the world's oldest tree!), and demand we prove the negative. Even if they do it enmasse.

I tracked down this issue of PREMIERE Magazine from March 1989.  In a short sidebar titled TALES OF PRERELEASE MADNESS they give Penny Marshall a chance to respond to why she went against the test audience wishes to have Susan join Josh.  She adds that the studio wanted it also.  Her reasons align with most people's thoughts, but I like how she doesn't mince words saying "Are they going to be doing it in junior high?"
The first line is a statement by the author of what the audience wanted.  They always reserve the best seats at these screenings for the press, so I am taking this as a firsthand account from the PREMIERE reporter.  It is just months since the movie has finished it's run.  Later other publications say the alternate ending tested poorly, but I think those are just making a wrong assumption. Also we are not certain an alternate ending was presented or if it was just suggested.


Final Cut
Tales of Prerelease Madness
Audiences at test screenings for the film lobbied for a "happy" ending, in which Elizabeth Perkins would join Tom Hanks in childhood.  "The ending that was always written in the script was that he went back and she didn't," says the film's director, Penny Marshall.  "At one point, the studio wanted her to go back.  We talked about it, but [coproducer] Jim Brooks and I didn't want to change it.  It was logic conversations:  What's she going to tell her parents?  Are they going to be doing it in junior high?  Also, this was the script the studio bought, and if they were worried about the ending being bittersweet, they should have worried about it a few years earlier."

